# How to sync with Google Calendar?

Tags: kubuntu, plasma-5

Can't seem to find how to sync the built in Calendar that comes with Kubuntu.

Here's what it shows me when I click "Configure Digital Clock":

[image]

And this is my System Information:[image]

Thank you :)

Comment: You have to add the calendar in Korganizer..see e.g. http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2017/05/how-to-setup-korganizer-for-google-calendar.html

Comment: Hmm. that's odd. Korganizer is a KDE product. Why wasn't it installed by default?

Comment: It's working. Thanks mate. The blog is outdated by the way, the options are different places in Korganizer.

Answer (score 4):

Try the widget called Event Calendar [link](https://zren.github.io/kde/widget/eventcalendar/).

For installation and setup, refer to its [github page](https://github.com/Zren/plasma-applet-eventcalendar)

It does the job

Answer (score 2):

Once you've installed and configured KOrganizer, you can use `kdepim-addons` to let the panel widget show its events.

1. install KOrganizer as described in totymedli answer
2. install kdepim-addons: `sudo apt install kdepim-addons`
3. Right click on the clock in the panel -> `Configure Digital Clock... -> Calendar -> Enable PIM Events Plugin`
4. Still in Digital Clock settings, go to `PIM Events Plugin` and check all the calendars you want to show in the KDE clock/calendar widget.

Credits: https://zren.github.io/2019/10/19/show-korganizer-events-in-the-panels-calendar

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can't do this. The closest thing is to install a desktop calendar and configure sync in it. For [KOrganizer](https://kde.org/applications/en/korganizer):

1. Install KOrganizer: `sudo apt-get install korganizer` the open it
2. Go to `Settings->Configure KOrganizer->General->Calendars tab` then Click `Add...`
3. Select "Google Calendars and Tasks" then click `OK`
4. On the top "Accounts" block then click `Add`
5. Login to you Google account then allow access to it
6. Check "Enable interval refresh" then set how often the syncing should happen
7. Select the calendars and tasklists you want to import then click `OK`